# how to insert flash video in magento cms page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, frontend

How to insert flash video in magento cms page.  I tried inserting video in the wyswyg editer. but it shows only a white background.
I want to show a promotional video on about us page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below and replace Your-Class-ID with your own and Your_Flash_File.swf with the name of your flash file.

Also, change the width and height with your own.

```
 <object classid="clsid:your-class-id" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width="475" height="375">
    <param name=movie value="{{skin url='images/media/your_flash_file.swf'}}">
                <param name=quality value=high>
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                <embed src="{{skin url='images/media/your_flash_file.swf'}}" quality=high wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="475" height="375">
                </embed> 
              </object>
```

Comment: Can you plz tell where to put above code.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this code which I have used in my site to locate video on cms page.

```
 <object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.swf"></object> 
    <OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="">
        <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="Yourfilename.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399> <EMBED src="Yourfilename.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="Yourfilename" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
    </OBJECT>
```

I hope that it will useful to you.